# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, swift

I am new to programming. I am going to learning iOS app development with the Apple new programming language Swift.
And I follow this site( https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=16 ) to start.
I copied the code from the video into my Xcode project. Anything was fine when I run the app in iOS 8.1 iOS simulator.
BUT I got exception while I choose iOS 7.1 iOS simulator. 
And I put the app into my iPhone 5S(iOS 7.1.2), it CRASHED.

Below is the code I copied from the video:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    @IBAction func applyFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image)

        let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]
        let filteredImage = inputImage.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust",withInputParameters: randomColor)
        let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent())

        photoImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Here is what I got from the console:

```
2014-11-03 16:17:30.645 njnj[2748:60b] -[CIImage imageByApplyingFilter:withInputParameters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe4e3d165e0
2014-11-03 16:17:30.649 njnj[2748:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CIImage imageByApplyingFilter:withInputParameters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe4e3d165e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c8b495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010852799e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d1c65d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c7cd8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c7c938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   njnj                                0x0000000106b934a0 _TFC4njnj14ViewController11applyFilterfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 3648
    6   njnj                                0x0000000106b93a66 _TToFC4njnj14ViewController11applyFilterfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010753af06 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010753af06 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010753aeb4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107617880 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107616dc0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107571d05 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 701
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001075726e4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 925
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010754a29a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000107537aed _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c1ad21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c1a5f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c3646f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c35d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010baf2f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000107539e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    22  njnj                                0x0000000106b9582e top_level_code + 78
    23  njnj                                0x0000000106b9586a main + 42
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108ee55fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.
(Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: The crash log complains about `imageByApplyingFilter:withInputParameters:`. Did you look-up that function in the documentation? According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/CoreImage.html, it was ***added*** in iOS 8.0.

Comment: @MartinR ，thanks a lot. I just google the "imageByApplyingFilter iOS 7.1", but i found nothing that i need. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you make sure your app's `Deployment Target` suits to a version of the device/simulator on which you want your app to run?

Comment: @findall The Deployment Target was already set to 7.1

Answer (score 0):

Usually "unrecognized selector sent to instance" (resulting from -doesNotRecognizeSelector:) indicates a memory management issue, often an over-release of an object that is still referenced somewhere.

I suggest you run a debug build with memory debugging to triage your app's memory issues.  I suggest you use ASan through recent versions of Xcode.  If that's not an option, you can use malloc history with guard malloc, scribble, and NSZombies.

Comment: Zombies helps debug BAD_ACCESS. Unrecognized selector means that the signature of the method you're trying to call is not found. It's a weird thing in Xcode that this error shows up at runtime when the binaries (such as a .framework) are not linked, embedded or copied. Particularly when the method is in a category.

Comment: Zombies helps debug over-releases leading to BAD_ACCESS because it keeps objects alive to catch those accesses.  It also helps debug over-releases leading to -doesNotRecognizeSelector:.  When one object is deallocated (with a reference still existing), another object can be created at that address, and then the a future access through the reference to the deallocated object will trigger -doesNotRecognizeSelector:.

Comment: I agree with your answer. Do you have one or two sample programs that demonstrate these two types of zombies? Or perhaps a link to a tutorial? thx